# Content sliders that also slide between http addresses

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I've noticed that some content sliders don't merely slide between content on a certain page, but actually take you to a different http but with the appearance of just sliding content on the same page. Here is an example website

[Link](http://estudiopatagon.com/tf/wp-vcard-colores/#2)

How is this achieved? Is another page in fact being visited? If this is the case why is only certain content being loaded but other content is remaining (such as everything that exists outside of the slider). I've been searching for a while but can't seem to find any similar questions or answers.

Comment: all the content is on same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL hash isn't a different page. A little HTML inspection reveals that there's a jQuery slider at play. You'll find a UL with a class of `wrapper`, and each child LI has a class of `box`. Those list items contain the content that's rotated in the page. All of it's inside `div.slider,` which is probably the selector that the plugin acts on.

Comment: Great thanks. As a side question, is it possible to load pages by leaving content that is identical from the previous page and only loading the content that differs on the new page?

Comment: Sure, if you're using ajax or iframes. I'm not sure how you're defining "new page", though. Is the URL changing?

Comment: Cool, thanks I'll look into that. Yes ideally the link would take you to a page with a different URL, can this still be achieved via ajax or iframes?

Comment: Sure, but you're jumping through hoops for no apparent benefit. Cross-browser history state can be messy. The browser caches much of your content anyway, so working that hard to load new pages in a wrapper may not have a significant payoff.

Comment: It's mainly for aesthetic purposes that I'd like to do this. For example on this website, http://www.aodlorimer.com/#!about/c139r       if you click on one of the links, the header stays where it is and doesn't need to be reloaded. I looks at the source code and it seems that its being achieved with javascript. I'd like to try and replicate it but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: That's a Wix site. They probably have some pretty heavy back-end page handling in place.